# BPM for SAP and Java systems from .net

Tags: .net, business-process-management

We are looking for a BPM tool that enables development in .NET but integrates to SAP and other Java systems - including transactional capabilities.

We are focused on the ability to modify workflows and deploy new solutions quickly.

We have considered Bonita and ProcessMaker (open-source) tools but they do not seem to provide the ease of use / maturity we are looking for - specifically a designer that can be easily used by .NET developers.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We are using [PNMSoft](http://www.pnmsoft.com) bpms and we are very happy with it.

We are a Python/.NET based organisation and we are constantly deploying new workflows/processes - it provides the capability to stage/deploy solutions quickly.

As for SAP - it includes native SAP XI connector that includes transactional capabilities so you can deploy workflows quickly. The same goes for Java/J2EE based solutions.

If you have a specific implementation/use case you are looking for I can be more specific.

J